# Add new features to a df based on a chr vector and make all values 0

Tags: r

I have a vector

```
> non_matches
 [1] ".outcome"        "special"         "attent"          "special_attent"  "assault_and"    
 [6] "and_batteri"     "ip"              "drug_poss"       "runaway"         "i_p"            
[11] "nuisanc"         "investig_person" "traff_acc"       "accident"        "aggravated"     
[16] "possession"      "vehicle"
```

I also have a data frame.

For each value in my vector, I would like to create a new feature on my df with a value of zero.

Tried:

```
library(foreach)
foreach(i = seq_len(length(non_matches))) %do% {
  pp_new_data$non_matches[i] <- 0
}
```

Also tried

```
library(foreach)
library(dplyr)
foreach(i = seq_len(length(non_matches))) %do% {
  pp_new_data <- mutate(pp_new_data, non_matches[i] = 0)
}
```

In both cases I failed.

How can I do the following using  a loop?

```
pp_new_data$.outcome <- 0
pp_new_data$special <- 0
pp_new_data$attent <- 0
etc.
```

Comment: What about `pp_new_data[non_matches] <- 0`?

Comment: I was not aware I could do that, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mutate_at` can modify a vector of column names. However, it applies a function, so we just create a function that always returns 0.

```
library('tidyverse')

pp_new_data <- tibble(dummy_data = c(1, 2, 3))
non_matches <- c('special', 'attent', 'special_attent', 'assault_and')

mutate_at(pp_new_data, non_matches, function(...) 0)
# # A tibble: 3 x 5
#   dummy_data special attent special_attent assault_and
#        <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>          <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1          1       0      0              0           0
# 2          2       0      0              0           0
# 3          3       0      0              0           0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach. You could modify it to have another for loop within if you wanted to assign different values for each column instead of 0.

```r
suppressMessages(library(dplyr))
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.4.2
non_matches <- c("special", "attent")
df <- mtcars
for(column_name in non_matches) {
  df <- df %>% mutate(!!column_name := 0)
}
head(df)
#>    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb special attent
#> 1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4       0      0
#> 2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4       0      0
#> 3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1       0      0
#> 4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1       0      0
#> 5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2       0      0
#> 6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1       0      0
```